# async TcpClient.Connect() how to use it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient

Currently I am connecting my client to the server synchronously.
However, the server is unavailable at times, so I figured using async would be better so I can already gather and format the data I want to send later. I found that the method I am looking for is probably [TcpClient.BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.beginconnect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Unfortunately I am completely new to async operation, so the parameters weird me out.
For one: Is there a specific reason I have to use IP and port seperately, i.e. not use an IPEndPoint?
The more important problem however: AsyncCallback and Object, what are these?
Do I need to change anything on my server?
I think I understood that snyc or asnyc is a local choice and doesn't affect the other side, at least not in compatibility.
Lastly: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) I read about keywords asnyc and await: Where to use them and how?

Here's a little pseudo-code to demonstrate what I have and what I want

```
private static void send(string msg) {
    TcpClient cli = new TcpClient(localEP);
    bool loop = true;
    while(loop) {      //trying over and over till it works
        try {          //is bad practice and inefficient
            cli.Connect(remoteEP);
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }
        if(cli.Connected)
            break;
    }
    var blah = doOtherThings(msg);
    useTheClient(blah);
}
```

And now how I wished it to work

```
private static void send(string msg) {
    TcpClient cli = new TcpClient(localEP);
    cli.BeginConnect(remoteEP); //thread doesn't block here anymore + no exceptions
    var blah = doOtherThings(msg); //this now gets done while cli is connecting
    await(cli.connect == done) //point to wait for connection to be established
    useTheClient(blah);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new `AsyncCallback` and set it to a specific void where something will be done once the `TcpClient` is finished connecting to the host. You might also want to check whether the `TcpClient` connection succeeded or not by checking the value of the `TcpClient.Connected`

**Example**

The following example illustrates the asynchronous `TcpClient` connection to google.com on port 80

```
static TcpClient cli = new TcpClient(); //Initialize a new TcpClient
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    send("Something");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void doSomething(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (cli.Connected) //Connected to host, do something
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected"); //Write 'Connected'
    }
    else
    {
        //Not connected, do something
    }
    Console.ReadLine(); //Wait for user input
}
private static void send(string msg)
{
    AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback(doSomething); //Set the callback to the doSomething void
    cli.BeginConnect("google.com", 80, callBack, cli); //Try to connect to Google on port 80
}
```

Here's a better way to do what you described in the comment

```
System.Threading.Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread((System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate {
//Do whatever you want in a new thread
    while (!cli.Connected)
    {
        //Do something
    }
});
newThread.Start(); //Start executing the code inside the thread
//This code will still run while the newThread is running
Console.ReadLine(); //Wait for user input
newThread.Abort(); //Stop the thread when the user inserts any thing
```

Comment: ok, this already looks way simpler than anything I found before. this means: "when connected, call `callback` and pass `"connected"`" and until then the code gets executed further down. Am I right so far? Are there any limitation on the design of the callback function in addition to only void type, like only one param being a IAsyncResult?

Now how can I define the point I don't want to pass before the asnyc event is through, i.e. the point past which it HAS to be connected and I cannot do anything else anymore?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the code will execute in background while your application runs normally. Then when the TcpClient has finished connecting or trying to connect, it'll run the callback void. The callback void then checks whether the TcpClient succeeded in connecting or not by checking the `cli.Connected` value, and sorry but I don't really get your last question, what do you mean?

Comment: Let's say, I want to establish the connection right when starting my program, but not do something specific with it yet, just have it done. Then I do various things and then I want to use the client. When its not connected yet I crash, so here I want to wait for it. Is there a simple way to wait for this other than `while(!cli.Connected);`?

Comment: @Mark That's nice, you can use `System.Threading.Thread` to start a new thread and do whatever you want without interfering with your main thread. I've edited the post to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I think that'll do.

Comment: One last thing: When you called beginconnect you passed string "connected": Where did that one go?

Comment: @Mark That was in the previous version of this post, I found out that checking `TcpClient.Connected` is a better option, so I edited the post. Here's the link of the first version if you would like to take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21136892/1

Comment: No thanks. I just wanted to be sure it doesn't have a deeper meaning. So I guess I could also pass null there.

Comment: @Mark Yes, since that we won't be using the passed value anyways. Have a nice day!